# Ruby - Render text without html tags

Tags: ruby, haml

I have a rich text input field where users can customize the text.

`= render :partial => "shared/rich_text", :locals => {:f => f, :field => :description, :label => "Description"}`

The problem is that the message gets rendered with the html tags:

`<p><ul><li>go to to add your email <b>false@someemailservice.com</b>, and <a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a> and www.othersite.com</li></ul></p>`

How can I change this to be rendered with the hyperlinks and not plain text with html tags?

Comment: The code you show uses a partial template.  What is the content of that partial template?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `html_safe`. As a security measure Rails by default escapes the string because there's a possibility of it having malicious code embedded inside. If you use `html_safe` you are telling Rails your string is safe to unescape.

```
<% @string = "<h1>String</h1>" %>
<%= @string.html_safe %>
```